# How to do logging in angular 2 and saving it in a file?

Tags: angular, logging

If I use Logger method of angular 2 I will not be able to save it in file .However external libraries such as log4js are not supported.

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow. You could look at something like loggly, which will store your logs

Comment: You should post logs it to a server from where it can be stored. Trying to do such of thing in the client is not the way to go as the Angular app runs on the client side then you don't have access to those logs.

Comment: Ok thank you .. Is it possible to  implement logging by modifying  log4js-node so as to be compatible with the typescript as it has file appenders?